# "Stacked" Advanced Filters Excel

Tags: excel, vba, filter, logic, advanced-filter

Is there a way to implement an advanced filter that would act like the following logic shown in the screenshot below? (the selected cells represent the desired logic)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub StackedFilter()

    Dim a As Variant, b As Variant, c As Variant

    a = Array("A", "B", "C")
    b = Array("D", "E", "F")
    c = Array("G", "H", "I")

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=a, Operator:=xlFilterValues  'Col A filter
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=b, Operator:=xlFilterValues  'Col A And B
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=c, Operator:=xlFilterValues  'Col A And B And C
    End With
End Sub
```